# Printing in window service after Log Off

Tags: c#, service, window

Is it possible to print a file or do anything through window service after user Log Off event?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for   `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents` and `SessionEnded` events to capture the log off using following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx

or in the following way

```
 BOOL WTSRegisterSessionNotification(
  __in  HWND hWnd,
  __in  DWORD dwFlags
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Rajesh: Do you happen to know if or how you can use system calls within a service?